# BroadcastReceiver not working for PendingIntent(...)

Tags: android

I am developing an SMS messaging application. The problem arose with BroadcastReceiver which check sent message or no. When I registrer him in activity, he works good. But I want to saddle him in the department class so that he will not be destroyed in the event of the closure of activity. Please help =(

```
 public void send(View view) {


        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";


        msg = mEditMessage.getText().toString();
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts = sm.divideMessage(msg);

        Intent iSent = new Intent(SENT);
        iSent.putExtra("id", lastId + 1);

        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iSent, 0);

        Intent iDel = new Intent(DELIVERED);
        iDel.putExtra("msg", msg);
        PendingIntent piDel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iDel, 0);

        progressSms = new Sms(lastId + 1, extraAddress, msg, "1", Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 2, imageUri,  extraName, true);
        updateAdapter(progressSms);


        if (parts.size() == 1)
        {
            msg = parts.get(0);
            sm.sendTextMessage(extraAddress, null, msg, piSent, piDel);
            compileMessage();

        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> delPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

            int ct = parts.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++)
            {
                sentPis.add(i, piSent);
                delPis.add(i, piDel);
            }

            sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(extraAddress, null, parts, sentPis, delPis);
```

```
public class SentSmsReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {//

    private String LOG_TAG = "sent_reciver";

    private SentListener sentListener;

    public SentSmsReciver(SentListener sentListener) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "create reciver");
        this.sentListener = sentListener;
    }

    private boolean failed = true;
    private Context context;
    private String id;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "create reciver");
        this.context = context;
        db = new SmsDbHelper(context.getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
        id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        switch(getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context,"SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                failed = false;
                compileMessage();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(context,"Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                compileMessage();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(context,"No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                compileMessage();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(context,"Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                compileMessage();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context,"Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                compileMessage();
                break;
        }
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.ciphermessanger">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name=".activity.MyIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".recivers.SentSmsReciver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".recivers.DeliverSmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SMS_DELIVERED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".activity.DialogActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.SmsListActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".recivers.SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".recivers.MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".services.HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".activity.ComposeSmsActvity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone will be mean
Start service and there register broadcast

```
public class MyIntentService extends Service {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        broadcastReceiver = new SentSmsReciver();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```